# simple count query take too much time to execute

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database having 36402933 records, but when i run the following simple query,

```
select count(user-id) 
from (Table) 
where time>'2006-04-07 22:59:59' 
and time<'2006-04-07 23:59:59 ';
```

It takes about 1 min to execute . in Mysql console. 
is there any better way to execute it fast ??

Comment: Please show the schema of the table, we can check for indices, and what @tanaydin noted, maybe you have varchar instead of time field

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(user-id)
FROM (Table)
WHERE time BETWEEN '2006-04-07 22:59:59'
AND '2006-04-07 23:59:59';
```

and also Create one INDEX of TIME field.

Answer (score 1):

You can create index on time field to make this query faster. But if it is varchar (seems so) it will always be a problem for you. Convert it to proper DateTime type and create index will be best solution.

Comment: good catch on the varchar! Submitter should provide creation schema of the table

Answer (score 1):

Yes, place an index on the time field.

And/or inspect the query plan, see if that brings some suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can do a couple of things.

1) Making sure that time are indexed

2) Place a limit on your result

```
SELECT count(`user-id`) 
    FROM (Table) 
    WHERE `time` >'2006-04-07 22:59:59' 
    AND `time` <'2006-04-07 23:59:59 ';
```

3) Increase your memory that is utilized by mysql to perform queries.

Comment: creating index on userid in his/her case won't make any difference